# domain of convergence of power series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to find radius of convergences and domain of convergence for the:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}3^{n^{2}}x^{n^{2}}$.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Please let us know what are your opinions on the problem, what have you tried?

Comment: You may wish to write the general term as $ \ (3x)^{n^2} \ $ .  This looks like a job for ... the Ratio Test!

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why didn't it work? You do remember the result stating that for a series to converge, the general term should $\to0$. Have you checked for which $x$ does that happen?

Comment: I tried to find radius and got:$ R=\frac{1}{\lim \sqrt[n]{3^{n^{2}}}}=0$

Answer (score 2):

Using the Cauchy test

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|3x|^{n^2}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{|3x|^{n}}<1\iff|x|<\frac{1}{3}$$
so the radius of convergence $R=\frac{1}{3}$ and it's clear that the series is divergent for $x=\pm \frac{1}{3}$ hence the domain of convergence is the interval $(-\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$.

Comment: Maybe he want the domain of convergence in the complex plane?  He didn't say.

Comment: @Sami Ben Romdhane Thank you. I tried to find the radius and got that: $R=\frac{1}{\lim \sqrt[n]{3^{n^{2}}}}=0$.. Why is it wrong?